# std::equal function with user-defined class

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to understand some sample code (see below). My understanding of the std:equal function was that when using user-defined types there had to be an equality == operator defined to allow the function perform a comparison.

So I don't understand how this int() operator (is it a cast?) performs the same function. Why would the equal function attempt to cast instances of class A to int?

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
   int a;

   A(int a) : a(a) {}
   operator int() const { return a; }  //LINE I
};

int main()
{
    set<A> s{ 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 9, 8, 2 };
    cout << equal(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin()) << endl;  //LINE II
}
```

Comment: You're not calling the `find` function.

Comment: sorry yes the code is calling std:equal. But the same question applies, how is the std:equal function comparing the elements. thanks

Comment: So fix either the code or the title to make them compatible. This is almost a good question.

Comment: done as you suggest. thanks

Comment: I fixed the title for you. It is a good question now :-)

Comment: No, _now_ it's a good question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can understand what's going on by looking at this code:

```
#include <iostream>


class A {
    public:
        int a;
        A(int a) :    a(a) {}
        //operator int() const {return a;}
};

int main () {

    A a{10};
    A b{20};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a == b) << std::endl; // does not compile
}
```

If you comment the conversion operator, the code does not compare. If you uncomment it, the code compiles, and the comparison is done by implicitly converting `a` and `b` to `int`.

This conversion is being performed because the standard operator `==` for `int`s is a good candidate in evaluating the expression `a == b`, so the compiler triggers an implicit conversion to `int` (thanks to @LightnessRacesinOrbit for pointing this out).

Comment: for the person who keeps downvoting, please read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal before you downvote, to understand how `std::equal` works

Comment: What's triggering the conversion to `int`? The extant `op==` for ints, perhaps.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `operator int()` is not `explicit`, so the compiler tries to convert it to `int` (which can then be used in `==`). If that's not the case, let me know, I don't want to post a wrong answer.

Comment: No, I believe it _is_ the case, but I'm trying to lead you into explaining that in the answer. Isn't the key here that there is a standard `op==` for `int` that is a candidate after the user-defined conversion from `A` to `int` is applied? Then you can answer the question "What's triggering the conversion to `int`", which I think is the real core of the OP. Objects don't just magically get converted to objects of other types willy-nilly when there happens to be a viable conversion path available to do so — something still needs to trigger it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, you're right, thanks, will clarify

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, and vsoftco thanks guys for the comments. What i understand from your answers is that the compiler is using a level of indirection in that it sees there is no equivalence operation for class A but there is a cast operation from A to int and that type int does have an equivalence operation. The compiler is obviously scanning the type for cast operations which I did not think it would be capable of doing.

Comment: @appdJava: Pretty much

Comment: "a good candidate" isn't enough. It must be the best viable candidate.